# Getting a timeout issue when trying to access nuget packages from nuget-gallery

Tags: artifactory, nugetgallery

I am trying to pull the package from artifactory but facing below issue.

Receiving the following error:

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-gallery/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
The HTTP request to 'GET http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-gallery/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' has timed out after 100000ms.
```

Comment: It's been a year but we have the same issue.
Do you managed to understand why you had "time out"?